# Loop back to question instead of printing out "Try again"? (C)

Tags: c, loops

this is my first day coding and I'm trying to see how the code work, how can I change Y/N to Yes/No and loop back questions if the answer is not Yes instead of printing out "Try again?" or make it better?

```
int main(void)
{

    char answer;
    int name;
    printf("Enter Username: \n");
    scanf("%s",&name);
    printf("Is your username \"%s\"? Enter Y or N\n", &name);

    while (scanf(" %c", &answer) == 1 && answer == 'Y')
    {
        char answer2;
        Sleep(1000);
        printf("Username confirmed\n");
        Sleep(2000);
        int pass;
        printf("Enter your password: \n");
        scanf("%s",&pass);
        printf("Is your password \"%s\"? Enter Y or N\n", &pass);
        while (scanf(" %c", &answer2) == 1 && answer2 == 'Y')
        {
            printf("Success!");
            Sleep(1000);
            exit;
        }
        printf("Try again..\n");
        Sleep(1000);
        exit;
    }
    Sleep(1000);
    printf("Try again..\n");
    Sleep(1000);
    exit;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to tell you how to spend your time, but I think if that's your first day of programming, you should learn at least the fundamentals "by yourself" (i.e. following courses, tutorials or reading a great book), and do some exercises, then ask more "sophisticated" questions here on StackOverflow

Comment: Help yourself visualize the what the code does by drawing some pictures. A *what it does* and a *what I need* flowchart, as old and outdated as it might sound, will work wonders figuring out what a program does with respect to what you need it to do.

Comment: Side note: Never write code without a plan. If you dive right into the code you'll find you debug your code until it becomes a plan, and this usually takes far, far longer than starting with a plan, debugging the plan, and then writing the code.

Comment: You might also find useful to write a meaningful comment for each piece of behaviour you need to implement, and then try to translate it to the actual code. However the best way to learn how to code is to read/study and try, try, try again and again :)

Comment: Before you think about entering `Yes` or `No` instead of `Y` or `N` the present code needs to be debugged. The `scanf("%s",&pass);` has the wrong format specifier to work with `int pass` and so does the `printf`. The `&` of `&pass` is also wrong in `printf`. But when you do, you'll need to enter a string, and make a (case-insensitive?) string comparison. You've done well so far, I commend you for having a significant space in the format string `scanf(" %c", &answer)`.

Answer (score 0):

My best advice, as [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) told you in the comment section, is to try to compile your code, before making changes: you'll find out that it won't even compile, since there are some errors (https://godbolt.org/z/MdahM4sT8).
You should debug and try to figure out why it doesn't work, fix it, then move to the new "features".

---

You probably want to change the `while()` condition and read a sequence of characters (array of `char`) instead of a single `char`.

```c
char answer[4];

while (scanf("%3s", answer) > 0 && strcmp(answer, "Yes") == 0)
```

`char answer[4];` creates an array of characters (which can be called a *string*, even though C doesn't have that abstraction) of size 4.
You might want to know why we need a size of 4, since the longer answer we can get is "Yes". Well, a string in C is a sequence of characters (`char`), ending with a special character, called **terminating character** `'\0'`.

Therefore, when you read a string with `scanf()`, you need to reserve some space for the terminating character aswell, and scanf() will add it when reading a space or carriage return after your input string. So if you enter "Yes" and then press the Return key, your `answer[4]` buffer will look like: `{'Y', 'e', 's', '\0'}`.
`%3s` tells scanf() to read only the first 3 characters of the string (prevents security issues like buffer overflow).

> `int scanf(const char *format, ...)`
>
> **Description**
> Reads formatted input from stdin.
>
> **Return Value**
> On success, the function returns the number of items of the argument list successfully read. If a reading error happens or the end-of-file is reached while reading, the proper indicator is set (feof or ferror) and, if either happens before any data could be successfully read, EOF is returned.

Once you've read that string, you can use `strcmp()`, a function defined in `<string.h> header, that takes in 2 string parameters, and returns:

- a `negative value` if the first precedes alphabetically the second;
- `0` if they're equal;
- a `positive integer` if the second precedes alphabetically the second;

Therefore you can check if `strcmp(answer, "Yes") == 0` to know if you've read `Yes`, and

Comment: `scanf("%s", answer)` ==> `scanf("%3s", answer)`. I would never use an array that is *exactly* the right length for a string response either. It's very unforgiving if someone enters `Yess`, when the last `s` will remain in the input buffer, but small input mistakes like that can be recovered if the buffer is bigger, say `char answer[42];`.

Comment: ... and `scanf("%41s", answer)`.

Comment: @WeatherVane You're right, actually there are so many more things that could be said (e.g. about his use of `exit`), but it feels like writing too much becomes sorta overwhelming, especially since it's his first day of coding...